# Reading from a file based on space delimiter

Tags: c

I have text file that contains 4 lines of data. Each line is as follows

```
Candies 2
Cookies -4
Soda 5
Milk 8
```

I have to read the the values (2,-4,5,8) in a C function and store them in a variable.

I have written the following code and I'm stuck at the point where I've indicated by XXXXXX. I'm not sure what exactly goes in there and after that. Appreciate your help.

```
  void function()
  {
    int count=0,value[4],length=0;

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("file.txt","r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file !\n");
      exit(1);  
    }

     char line[100];
        for (count = 0; count < 4; count++)
        {      
            if (fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp)==NULL)
        break;

        else 
    {  

       while(fp!="" && length<strlen(line))
       {
       fp++;length++
       }

       if(fp == "") 
         value[count]= XXXXXXXX;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hint: You'll probably want to use `fscanf()`.

Comment: I recommend keeping the `fgets` and then use `sscanf` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please *don't* increment `fp`.  It does not do what you think it does.

If you want to do this with minimal help from existing C functions, simply search through your line for a space (okay, I used `isspace` and `atoi` here):

```
int pos = 0;
while( line[pos] != 0 && !isspace(line[pos]) ) pos++;
if( line[pos] != 0 ) {
    line[pos++] = 0;
    value[count] = atoi( &line[pos] );
    printf( "Key: '%s' / Value: %d\n", line, value[count] );
}
```

Or you could use `sscanf`...

```
int nread = sscanf( line, "%*s %d", &value[count] );
```

Or:

```
char key[100];
int nread = sscanf( line, "%s %d", key, &value[count] );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void function()
 {
    int count=0,value[4],length=0;

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("file.txt","r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file !\n");
      exit(1);  
    }

     char line[100];
        for (count = 0; count < 4; count++)
        {      
            if (fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp)==NULL)
                break;

          else 
            {  
              sscanf(line,"%*s %d",&value[count]);
            }
      }
```

I have modify the code ,you can try it.

Comment: Thank you! 

When I implemented it array named values gets only junk values. I tried it by making the array global and printing the its values in main function an but its still the same.

Comment: Make sure there's no definition in the funciton and only definited the array global.